# full crawl completed status - sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

Environment : SharePoint 2013

How to get full crawl ran status (full crawl completed status)?
I need to know when it is completed and successful/failed or any errors.

Comment: Check This : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/start-pause-resume-or-stop-a-crawl

Comment: there is no exact results what i am searching, could you please provide the details to get the completed crawl details

Comment: have you tried the below solutions..?

Answer (score 1):

[Source Link](https://vigneshsharepointthoughts.com/2016/01/13/working-with-search-crawl-logs-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**Steps to access the search crawl log in SharePoint 2013:**

Verify whether you’re an administrator for the Search service application.

In Central Administration, in the Quick Launch, click Application Management.

On the Application Management page, under Service Applications, click Manage service applications.

On the Service Applications page, in the list of service applications, click the Search service application that you want.

On the Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, under Crawling, click Crawl Log.

On the Crawl Log – Content Source page, click the view that you want.

Now if you take a closer look at the "crawl log" page you will see different views such as ….

Content source.

Host Name.

Crawl History

Error Breakdown

Databases

URL View
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Our member TARUN already provided an answer - just want to point out that the report can also be generated via PowerShell. If you need to automate report creation and get it quite frequently, consider automating this script with Task Scheduler - see step-by-step [guide by Jeff Melnick](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/).

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Parameters
$ContentSourceName = "Local SharePoint sites"
$ResultsCount = 10

#Get Search Service application and Content Source
$SearchServiceApplication = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ContentSource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $searchServiceApplication | ? { $_.Name -eq $contentSourceName }

#Get Crawl History
$CrawlLog = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlLog($searchServiceApplication)
$CrawlHistory = $CrawlLog.GetCrawlHistory($ResultsCount, $ContentSource.Id)

#Export the Crawl History to CSV
$CrawlHistory | Export-CSV "C:\CrawlHistory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

All credits goes to [Salaudeen Rajack](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-search-crawl-log-history-report.html)

Comment: Thanks Tons, thanks again for your timely response..